# "An error occurred while updating..." status:12152 and status:12029

Tags: xpages

We have been getting an error prompt/alert in our XPages application at random times:

"An error occurred while updating some of the page...status:12152" and
"An error occurred while updating some of the page...status:12029"

We can't seem to pin it down to anything. Maybe someone has an idea of what these errors are referring to or maybe how to track it back to something? Thanks.

[image: Status error:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP 12152 error usually points to a network connection issue rather than anything specific to the browser or the Domino server.12029 again is down to an inability to make a connection to the server.

It sounds like the network connection is intermittent. I don't know what tools there are to test that, but I would suggest confirming you have a good, stable network connection between PC and server and that it's not getting negatively impacted by a firewall.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I'll look into this. It doesn't seem to occur on our development server much, but it does occur on the test server almost on a daily basis (both servers are setup very similar). We are trying to figure this out before we roll this application into production.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your application is trying to partially refresh content on the screen, and that this partial refresh fails. This can be because the component with that id is no longer found in the component tree.

Have a look at your XPages source code for controls with an id of MainContent and refreshPanel3 and find any partial refreshes on those controls. Check the rendered/loaded property for these controls to see if they are hidden in certain cases. If you do not render a control and want to display it using a partial refresh, you must partially refresh an outer component that contains the non-rendered control.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but if the control isn't being rendered at all and the partial occurs, wouldn't this throw an error saying it couldn't even find the control?

Answer (score 0):

Use browser's network debug (F12 in Chrome/IE/Firefox w Firebug) to get real server response, it usually contains error page with more info. Failed partial refresh should be the last POST request.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Frantisek.